# How to update a results from a function incrementally in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that takes  12 seconds to run. I have made the function as efficient as possible using numba etc.

Are there any tricks for recalculating the function for only new data rows when new data is added incrementally to the end of the initial data set?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def complex_func(data):

    a = my_func1(data)  # Complex slow to run

    b = my_func2(a)     # Complex slow to run

    return b

def main():

    data = create_data()    # Data has millions of rows.

    starttime = time.time()
    while True:
        result = complex_func(data)

        data = append_new_row(data)
        
        time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))
```

Comment: This depends entirely on what your functions actually do.

Comment: Save the old data result as cache in file or database.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the function which appends new data, you could also perform the analysis. Then you can keep `result` as a variable outside your `while` loop.

E.g.

```
def main():
    data = create_data()    # Data has millions of rows.
    starttime = time.time()
    result = complex_func(data)

    while True:
        data, result = append_new_row(data)
        time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 5.0))

def append_new_row(data, old_result):
    logic to append, or not...

    if row_added:
        return new_data, complex_func(new_data)
    else:
        return data, old_result
```

The idea is to let `append_new_row` decide whether to recalculate the `complex_func` or not. The loop doesn't care whether new data is added, it just keeps track of what `append_new_row` says is the latest `data` and `result`.

Comment: But complex_func() running just on new_data would not have all the previous results. Imagine is complex_func() was just a simple rolling.mean - it would still need the previous "roll" to be correct.

Comment: does not `complex_func` just take one argument, `data`, as in your example above? If you can do it in the `while` loop as in your example, why can't you do it in `append_new_row`?

Comment: No, but I guess it could do.

Comment: you can always add extra arguments to `complex_func` if necessary, and in the pseudocode I've written above, `append_new_row` has an `old_result` argument you could pass to `complex_func`

Comment: Yes, but then complex_func() would have to be written expecting to use existing old_result. That is possible, but I am trying to see if there is some hack that allows me to update complex_func() without writing it that way specifically. I would like to keep the logic of complex_func() clean

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use a class or a closure to maintain the current state if that state can be cleanly updated based on only new data. In this case, we will use a closure that simply keeps track of a total and count from prior inputs to return an updated average when given "new" data. This emulates your suggestion to:

> "Imagine if complex_func() was just a simple rolling.mean"

```
## -------------------------
## our closure to maintain state.
## -------------------------
def make_my_func1():
  running_total = 0
  running_count = 0

  def do_work(partial_data):
    nonlocal  running_count, running_total
    running_count += len(partial_data)
    running_total += sum(partial_data)
    return running_total / running_count

  return do_work
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## the closure produces a function that we will call with "new" data rows
## -------------------------
my_func1 = make_my_func1()
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## just echo back the input for demo purposes
## -------------------------
def my_func2(data):
  return data
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## Your demo function
## -------------------------
def complex_func(data):
  a = my_func1(data)  # Complex slow to run (returns a running average at the moment)
  b = my_func2(a)     # Complex slow to run (just echos back what it was given at the moment)
  return b
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
# seed with big payload
## -------------------------
result = complex_func([1,2,3,4])
print(result)
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
# now get result based on just a "new" data point
## -------------------------
result = complex_func([5])
print(result)
## -------------------------
```

This will print:

```
2.5
3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. But I am trying NOT to have to build my functions in this way. I would like them to only contain the logic for their purpose(i.e rolling.mean()). I am looking for some hack that let's me update that function only with new data. I am aware that this is very likely IMPOSSIBLE - but I thought I had better ask...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by `rolling.mean()` if you rename `my_funct1()` to `rolling_mean()` does it not do what you seek? If the issue is that you want to passing complete data every call and have `my_funct1()` determine new rows itself, then that is also possible if you want me to update the answer that way let me know

Comment: Hi, what I am looking for is NOT to have my functions be aware that they are being updated sequential rather than as a vector call. I am looking for a library that does this without my having to code it. explicitly.